# Algorithm to derive possible combinations of a set e.g., $A = [1, 2, 3, 4]$ and $k = 3$ and $L = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]$

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations

Given a set of numbers A and an integer k, I want to derive a list of sets L such that all the sets in L are the distinct combinations of the elements in A picking k at a time.

For example: $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $k = 3$ and $L = \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 4\}, \{1, 3, 4\}, \{2, 3, 4\}\}$.

Note that len(L) = len(A) combination k

Example 2: $A = \{2, 3, 5\}$ and $k = 2$ and $L = \{\{2, 3\}, \{2, 5\}, \{3, 5\}\}$.

My question is, is there any such algorithm out there?

Do you have any relevant links that would assist me?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: Have you researched or searched on line yourself, for algorithms, or on line for combination/combinatorics instruction or texts?  Seems you expect us to answer your questions for you?

Comment: +1 : to your question, for clearly detailing what you want.  My only complaint about your posting is that you did not use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).    MathSE reviewers are going to wonder why I upvoted your question and answered it.  It is because you clearly detailed what you want, and there is no reason to believe that you have any Math training.  Therefore, in my opinion, your question is high quality, rather than low quality.

Comment: @amWhy Please, when be careful when editing questions.

Comment: "I want to derive a list of sets" are you sure about that?  Exponential memory use is a really bad thing.

Comment: A reference: Algorithm L (lexicographic combinations) in section 7.2.1.3 of *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 4A, Combinatorial Algorithms, Part 1, by Donald E. Knuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the other answer and [linked python method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), here is a recursive Python script that I don't think is too difficult to follow.

```
def comb(a,k):
    if k==0: return [[]]
    if k==len(a): return [a[:]]
    out = []
    out += comb(a[:-1],k)
    out += [s + [a[-1]] for s in comb(a[:-1],k-1)]
    return out
```

For example, `comb([1,2,3,4],3)` produces `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]`.

The algorithm works recursively in the following way: in the base case where $k = 0$, we return `[[]]` (the list containing only an empty list, corresponding to the fact that the empty subset is the only set with zero elements). If $k$ is the size of the whole set, we return a list containing the entire set, which is the only subset of size $k$.

In all other cases we work recursively, producing a list of subsets that do not contain the final element, followed by the subsets that do contain the final element.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to demonstrate (one possible) algorithm is by example.  Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}, ~k = 5.$

Re-index $A$, so that the elements, in reverse order are
$\{9,8,7,\cdots,2,1,0\}$.  When considering the number of subsets, in general, each element may or may not be in the subset.  So, there are $2^{10}$ possible subsets, if you include the entire set $A$, and the empty set.

There is a clear bijection between the collection of these $2^{10}$ possible subsets, and the set of all $(10)$ digit *zero-filled-on-the-left* binary numbers, that run from $0$ through $2^{10} - 1.$

What you are looking for, in this particular example, is all such binary numbers that have exactly $5$ digits that are [1], and (since the numbers are zero-filled) $5$ digits that are [0].

There is a clear bijection between such satisfying base-2 numbers (that have exactly $5$ [1]'s and is less than $2^{10}$) and the collection of desired subsets.

For example, the binary digit $0100011110$, would biject to the subset $\{8,4,3,2,1\}.$

This approach easily generalizes to any $n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}$ and $k \in \{1,2,\cdots, (n-1)\}.$

So, all that your computer program has to do is loop through each of the $2^{n}$ integers, that start at $(0)$, and end at $2^{n} - 1.$  For each such base-10 number, convert it to base-2, and count the number of non-zero elements in its base-2 representation.

Reject all such numbers that do not have exactly $k$ non-zero elements (i.e. the element [1]).  For those numbers that are not rejected, form the subset by reading the (zero-filled) number from left to right.

Each base-2 digit that equals [1] corresponds to an element that belongs in the subset that corresponds to this particular satisfying base-2 representation.

Comment: This is definitely not as efficient as it can be. For example, one approach is to work recursively: the subsets of $S = \{1,\dots,10\}$ of size $5$ are the subsets of $\{1,\dots,9\}$ of size $4$ with a $10$ appended, together with the subsets of $\{1,\dots,9\}$ of size $5$ (with no elements added).

Comment: @BenGrossmann See the comment that I left, following the question.  The target audience is very plausibly someone with no Math training or Math intuition.  Therefore, you want the algorithm  as well as the justification for the algorithm to be immediately clear.  I gave priority to simplicity of approach, which facilitates the OP's (i.e. original poster's) understanding.  There is no reason to suspect that more efficient use of the PC's CPU will be relevant to the original poster.

Comment: First of all, I don't see how your method is any easier to understand than a basic recursive function; what background do you imagine that OP has exactly? Second, I'm normally not a stickler for performance, but we're comparing exponential to polynomial performance here. For $|A| = 25$ and $k=3$, I'm finding that the recursive approach takes about 3 ms while your enumerative approach takes 16 s, and your approach doubles in computation time for every additional element of $A$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann In my personal experience running simulations on a PC, the PC can handle $(10)^7$ cases fine, and starts to balk somewhere between $(10)^7$ or $(10)^8$ cases.  Also, I suspect that the OP is someone who did not immediately know the answer to the question that they asked.  This explains why they posted the question.  Beyond that, we will have to agree to disagree on which posting would be easier (for example) for a high school student with some programming experience to understand.  ...see next comment

Comment: @BenGrossmann Personally, I think the issue is not whether the OP will be able to follow your answer.  Instead, I think the issue is whether it is plausible that the OP will be able to follow your answer and not be able to follow mine.